# First show all <tr> elements, then hide all except one class

Tags: jquery

I have different classes which I use to filter the content of a table. How can I edit this code, so after clicking on button (#aipa) first view all `<tr>` elements, and after that display (filter) only rows with class.? Now when i filter for example AIPA elements then I can't filter any other elements from table.

```
$("#aipa").click(function(){
        $('tr:not(:first)').not(".AIPA").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Is it working the first time? Where in the HTML are the filter buttons?

Comment: Or is the issue making the sample code generic for any filter?

Comment: here is my project http://miszkowice.ehost.pl/miecho/category/piwo/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#aipa").click(function(){
      $('tr').hide(); // hiding all trs
      $("tr.AIPA").fadeIn('fast'); // showing the tr havin AIPA class
   });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/3yVNX/)

If you want to hide all rows except `first row` and rows having `.AIPA class` the try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#aipa").click(function(){
       $("tr:not(:first, .AIPA)").fadeOut(1000);
   });
});
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/3yVNX/1/)

Comment: This hides the first `tr`, presumably the header row. Also, it's not clear if the issue is with the OPs code in general or after initial use or making it generic, etc

Comment: Thank You. Why You use '$('tr').hide();'? This hide all 'trs' and I need to display firstly all 'trs'. '$('tr').show();' did'nt work.

Comment: Thank You. This works great with one class. But when I have f.E. two ore more classes, like actually in my project I have AIPA and Black IPA classes. When I filtered only AIPA classes I can't filter after that rows with Black IPA. I must click again on AIPA button (toggle function) and now I'm able to filter Black IPA rows. Here is url of my project [link]http://miszkowice.ehost.pl/miecho/category/piwo/

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine them like this:

```
$('tr:not(":first, .AIPA")').slideToggle('fast');
```

Or may be this might help you:

```
$('tr:not(:first)').add(':not(".AIPA")').slideToggle('fast');
```